# ElasticSearch 1.5 upgrade: JodaTime conversion script error

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch, jodatime

I'm working through upgrading our ElasticSearch version from 1.3 to 1.5. We use the Java API heavily. the following script in an ES query:

```
 {
  "script" : {
    "script" : "values contains (int)doc['timestamp'].date.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID('America/New_York')).getMonthOfYear()",
    "params" : {
      "values" : [ 1 ]
    },
    "lang" : "groovy"
  }
}
```

This works with 1.3, but gives the following error in 1.5:

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[XwOu9zq0TMi2uOptdfIS7w][eventdata][0]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[eventdata][0]: query[filtered(ConstantScore(ScriptFilter(values contains (int)doc['timestamp'].date.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID('America/New_York')).getMonthOfYear().toString())))->cache(org.elasticsearch.index.search.nested.NonNestedDocsFilter@2a8c0465)],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingMethodException[No signature of method: Script1.contains() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [int]
Possible solutions: toString(), toString(), notify()]]; }
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:238)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$1.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:184)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:565)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

What's the best way to address this?

Comment: Can you try putting brackets in? Looks like it's doing `contains(int)` ie: `values.contains((int)doc['timestamp'].date.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID('America/New_York')).getMonthOfYear())`

Comment: @tim_yates I'd add that as an answer. I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a brackets issue with the cast, so it thinks you're passing `int` to contains. Try adding brackets to help out the parser:

```
values.contains((int)doc['timestamp'].date.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID('Ameri‌​ca/New_York')).getMonthOfYear())
```

Comment: this was it! I've tested and confirmed. thank you very much.